# Multiple clauses in EUnit's assertMatch?

Tags: erlang, eunit

I am using Erlang's [EUnit](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html) for unit testing an application.

I want to assert that a certain test value is between 2 and 3.  [There's no built-in support for this](https://github.com/richcarl/eunit/issues/10), so I am trying to use a pair of guards, like this:

```
myTestCase ->
  ?assertMatch({ok, V} when V>2, V<3,
               unitUnderTest() % expected to return 2.54232...
  ).
```

This tries to use the [guard syntax](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions) for `andalso`.

However, this does not work, presumably because Erlang's parser can't tell the difference between multiple guards and multiple arguments to `assertMatch`.  I tried wrapping various things in parentheses, but haven't found anything that works.  On the other hand, when I reduce the expression to just one clause, it succeeds.

Is there a way to express multiple clauses here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use commas in the syntax, simply because then ?assertMatch is interpreted as a macro with 3 - or more - parameters, and there is no definition for that. But the syntax andalso and orelse works. Why don't you use :

```
fok() -> {ok,2.7}.

fko() -> {ok,3.7}.

myTestCase(F) ->
    F1 = fun() -> apply(?MODULE,F,[]) end,
    ?assertMatch({ok, V} when V>2 andalso V<3, F1()).
```

test:

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:myTestCase(fok).
ok
3> test:myTestCase(fko).
** exception error: {assertMatch,
                        [{module,test},
                         {line,30},
                         {expression,"F1 ( )"},
                         {pattern,"{ ok , V } when V > 2 andalso V < 3"},
                         {value,{ok,3.7}}]}
     in function  test:'-myTestCase/1-fun-1-'/1 (test.erl, line 30)
4>
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, this does not work, presumably because Erlang's parser can't
>   tell the difference between multiple guards and multiple arguments to
>   assertMatch

The [eunit docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html) explicitly warn about that:

> `assertMatch(GuardedPattern, Expr)`
>
> GuardedPattern can be anything that you can write on the left hand
>   side of the -> symbol in a case-clause, except that it cannot contain
>   comma-separated guard tests.

How about:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

f() ->
    {ok, 3}.


f_test() ->
    ?LET({ok, X}, f(), ?assertMatch( true, X>2 andalso X<4 ) ).
```

Comment: You can replace `?assertMatch(true, Exp)` with just `?assert(Exp)` there.